# $(a_{1}+ a_{2} + ....+a_{k})^{n}$ where $k >2$, what does it generate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Binomial expansion generates the Pascal triangle but what does it generate when you have different amount of terms there?

You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) the geometric generation with only 2 terms. I am interested to know if you have many terms.

Comment: Do you mean Pascal's triangle?  What is up with z and h?  How many terms are inside parentheses?  Do you mean something like $(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k)^n$ where $k$ is an integer greater than $2$?  You get multinomial coefficients: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: yes, thanks.

Comment: @hhh: feel free to edit the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: multinomial theorem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: In particular, see the section [Generalized Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Generalized_Pascal.27s_triangle) and the articles linked there, [Pascal's pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid) and [Pascal's simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_simplex)